# ISC-DHCP, Defining a new token in the configure script

Tags: c, configure, autoconf, automake

I'm working on a patch for the ISC dhcp server to allow it to run correctly with Solaris 11 / Illumos NIC vanity names and Crossbow VNIC's.

By default, the tokens "__sun" and "_SVR4" are defined, but this applies to all versions of Solaris. I want to define "__SunOS_5_11" only if uname returns Solaris 11, because this patch only applies to Solaris 11. I believe the correct way to do this is in the configure script.

I've spent the past couple of days trying to decipher the configure script to no avail, it's quite large. I can gather that it generates a "config.h" file that contains token definitions though.

I believe they are using autoconf and automake, which i don't have a ton of experience with. If anyone has any experience with this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please remember that the "configure" script is autogenerated, and not to be edited, you're suppose to do this in the configure.ac

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by nos, i should be looking in configure.ac

i was able to pull this off with the following code.

```
# Solaris 11 / Illumos 11 is identified as solaris2.11
AM_CONDITIONAL([SOLARIS_2_11], [test x$host_os = xsolaris2.11])

# If host_os is solaris2.11 then define __SOLARIS_2_11
AM_COND_IF([SOLARIS_2_11],[AC_DEFINE([__SOLARIS_2_11], [1],
    [Define if host_os is solaris2.11])])
```